I did a proxmox offline vm migration, and it can't mount the storage on the destination node, how do I fix the storage definition?
I'm playing around with a test setup of proxmox to learn a bit and this is what I have and what I did:
I have two nodes, call them A and B. On A, I set up a vm with local storage. I made a "directory" that points to a partition on a local disk, let's call that A-directory. I installed an OS the vm it works great, all is well.
I shut down the vm and tried to do an offline migration to node B.
It complained that there was no storage named A-directory on node B.
So I went to datacenter->storage and edited A-directory. I selected node B as another option in the "Nodes" dropdown.
Then I did the offline migration again and it seemed to work. It moved the qemu file from node A to node B.
The problem is that it moved the qemu file to a directory in an existing storage pool I had on node B. It's in the correct place, but it is a simple directory, not a mountpoint.
When I try to start the vm, I get the error:
TASK ERROR: unable to activate storage 'A-directory' - directory is expected to be a mount point but is not mounted: '/mnt/pve/A-directory'

/mnt/pve/A-directory is a directory and within it, is images/102/vm-102-disk.qcow.
So the right file is in the right place, but because proxmox is expecting it to be a mountpoint and not a normal directory, it fails with the above error.
In /etc/pve/storage.cfg on node B, I have this:
dir: A-directory
    path /mnt/pve/A-directory
    content images,snippets,vztmpl,iso,backup,rootdir
    is_mountpoint 1
    nodes A,B
    shared 0

I tried changing the is_mountpoint to 0 and then it gets past that check when starting the vm, but fails to find the disk at all so it won't boot.
I at one point had tried making a storage directory manually on node B called "A-directory" but proxmox complained that that name was already in use. That's what tipped me off to add the other node to the existing storage definition in the first place.
So my questions:

Why did proxmox allow me to get into this situation.
How do I get out of it?
What is the correct way to do an offline migration if I have storage defined as a "directory" which is really more of a partition definition with a filesystem on it.

I've googled and googled and I can't seem to find a lot of information on how offline migrations are supposed to work. It did correctly move the data to the correct place on the correct node, but proxmox didn't give me the opportunity to define the destination storage the way it expects it to be. Maybe I missed something.
Hope that all makes sense.
Thanks for any help you can provide.
EDIT:
So I looked under node B -> 102 (the vm id) -> options and I noticed that Boot Order listed my storage A-directory, but it was deselected. I selected it, and changed the storage.cfg is_mountpoint to 0 and then the vm booted.
So that solves the immediate problem, offline migrations work, but I'm clearly missing something if I have to update storage.cfg to get it working.
Any thoughts?
